# extracting co-ordinates from table and analyzing them

Tags: postgresql

I am working on spatiotemporal data which includes date time and geom columns.

I have extracted x& y co-ordinate but want to find centroid of certain attribute but was not able to do so.

Any ideas?

Comment: select ST_x(geom), ST_y(geom) from [table_name] where point=25;

Comment: But i want to add some code here to get centroid so tried up doing this::
 
select ST_Centroid(ST_x(geom), ST_y(geom)) from [table_name] where point=25;

But this didn't worked out....